# CheckBox lists in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, checkboxlist

I am working on small ticket system for operations maintenance services comp.

- Customer open a ticket and gives general information like location,
  category description etc.
- After technician fix the problem he must give sum details of the
  problem from predefined set, use later for statistical reports.

My problem the repair method unable to post updated values to database plus nothing added to Defects_List table.

Note: I used [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial as guide

**Models:**

```
public partial class Tickets
{ 
    public Tickets()
    {
        this.DefectsList = new HashSet<Defects_List>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Ticket Id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Project")]
    public int Project_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Issue Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Issue_Date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "[Not set]")]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }

//Other Properties Removed for clarity

    public virtual Business_Category businessCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Defects_List> DefectsList { get; set; }
}
public partial class Business_Category
{
    public Business_Categories()
    {
        this.Tickets = new HashSet<Tickets>();
        this.Malfunctions = new HashSet<Malfunctions>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name="Category Id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name (eng)")]
    [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be longer than 60 characters.")]
    public string Category_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Manufacturers> Manufacturers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Malfunctions> Malfunctions { get; set; }
}

public partial class Defects_List
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [Display(Name = "Ticket Id")]
    public int Ticket_Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [Display(Name = "Malfunction Id")]
    public int Malfunction_Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(125, ErrorMessage = "Other cannot be longer than 125  characters.")]
    public string Other { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
    public virtual Malfunctions Malfunctions { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
// GET: /Tickets/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Repair(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var tickets = db.nt_Tickets
                   .Include(t => t.DefectsList).Where(t => t.Ticket_Id == id)
                   .Single();

        if (tickets == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        PopulateSelectedDefects(tickets);

        //Other codes Removed for clarity

        return View(tickets);
    }

    private void PopulateSelectedDefects(nt_Tickets Tickets)
    {
        int categoryId;

        if (Tickets.Category_Id == 2)
            categoryId = 1;
        else categoryId = Tickets.Category_Id;

        var allDefects = (from m in db.sys_Malfunctions
                        where m.Category_Id == categoryId
                        select m).ToList();

       var ticketDefects = new HashSet<int>(Tickets.DefectsList.Select(t => t.Malfunction_Id));
        var viewModel = new List<TicketDefectsViewModel>();

        foreach (var defect in allDefects)
        {
            viewModel.Add(new TicketDefectsViewModel
            {
                Malfunction_Id = defect.Malfunction_Id,
                Malfunction_Name_e = defect.Malfunction_Name_e,
                IsSelected = ticketDefects.Contains(defect.Malfunction_Id)
            });
        }

        ViewBag.Defects = viewModel;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Repair(int? id, string[] selectedDefects)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var ticketToUpdate = db.nt_Tickets
           .Include(i => i.DefectsList)
           .Where(i => i.Ticket_Id == id)
           .Single();

        if (TryUpdateModel(ticketToUpdate, "",
new string[] {   Ticket_Id,Project_Id,Category_Id,Subject,Workshop_Id,Requested_By,Requestor_Mobile,  Requestor_eMail,Location_Id,Ticket_Status,Periority_Id,Assigned_To,Description,Issue_Date,Created_By,Created_Date,Updated_By,Updated_Date" }))
{
            ticketToUpdate.Updated_By = User.Identity.Name;
            ticketToUpdate.Updated_Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
            db.Entry(ticketToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            SetTicketDefects(selectedDefects, ticketToUpdate);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                Exception raise = dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                            ViewBag.errorMessage = message;
                    }

                    return View("Error");
                }
                throw raise;
            }
        }

        PopulateSelectedDefects(ticketToUpdate);

        return View("Index");
    }


    private void SetTicketDefects(string[] selectedDefects, Tickets ticketToUpdate)
    {
        if (selectedDefects == null)
        {
            ticketToUpdate.DefectsList = new List<Defects_List>();
            return;
        }

        var selectedDefectsHS = new HashSet<string>(selectedDefects);

        var tcketDefects = new HashSet<int>
            (ticketToUpdate.DefectsList.Select(c => c.Ticket_Id));

        foreach (var defect in db.DefectsLists)
        {
            if (selectedDefectsHS.Contains(defect.Malfunction_Id.ToString()))
            {
                if (!tcketDefects.Contains(defect.Malfunction_Id))
                {
                    ticketToUpdate.DefectsList.Add(defect);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (tcketDefects.Contains(defect.Malfunction_Id))
                {
                    ticketToUpdate.DefectsList.Remove(defect);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

db.DefectsLists here [foreach (var defect in db.DefectsLists)] always empty.

**Repair View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Repair", "Tickets", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
@*@using (Html.BeginForm())*@
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ticket_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Issue_Date)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created_By)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project_Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Created_Date)        

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Ticket_Id", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-1 " style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ticket_Id)
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Issue_Date, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Issue_Date, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category_Id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DropDownList("Category_Id", null, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requested_By, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-5" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Requested_By, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requestor_Mobile, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Requestor_Mobile, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Requestor_eMail, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Requestor_eMail, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Ticket_Status, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Ticket_Status, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Periority_Id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:7px">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Periority_Id, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location_Id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownList("Location_Id", null, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_Id)
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Assigned_To, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownList("Assigned_To", null, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Label("Defects")
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    @{
                        int cnt = 0;
                        List<MaintCare.ViewModels.TicketDefectsViewModel> defects = ViewBag.Defects;
                        foreach (var defect in defects)
                        {
                            if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                            {
                                @:</tr><tr>
                            }
                            @:<td>
                <input type="checkbox"
                       name="selectedDefects"
                       value="@defect.Malfunction_Id"
                       @(Html.Raw(defect.IsSelected ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                @defect.Malfunction_Name_e

                                @:</td>
                        }
                        @:</tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: I believe your checkbox's `name` attribute should be `Defects[]`

Comment: Is your db.DefectsLists referencing a DB context? If yes, you may pass checkbox values as property array and process them on controller code.

Comment: if you place a breakpoint in the post method of the controller. does this get hit?

Comment: Do you get any values in ViewBag.Defects updated from viewModal? If it comes empty, please check whether you have data in the ViewBag.Defects.